# React native scrollview is missing content at the bottom when the content gets scrollable

Tags: react-native, android-scrollview

I have the following react native ScrollView wrapping one page of my app.
It works totally fine in portrait mode, but as soon as I switch to landscape mode, I can't see the bottom 48px.
When I add the bottom padding it looks good in landscape mode but I have too much padding in portrait mode.
Is there an easy solution how I can format the content correctlky in landscape and portrait mode?

Maybe it is has something to do with the fact that the content is not scrollable in portrait mode due to it´s height.

```
    <ScrollView
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
      contentContainerStyle={{
        margin: 24,
        marginTop: 48,
        // paddingBottom: 48,
        alignItems: "center",
        flexGrow: 1,
      }}
    >
```

Comment: There isn't really enough here to reproduce the problem, can you add a [mcve] please?